# I want to connect 2 containers with each other in a Docker-Swarm

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, containers, docker-swarm

I want to connect two containers with each other ... I start with the creation of an overlay-network `mynet`:

```
docker network create -d overlay mynet
```

After that, I´ve created the first service `activemq`:

```
docker service create --name activemq -p 61616:61616 -p 8161:8161  --replicas 1 --network mynet rmohr/activemq
```

This starts and works perfectly fine, I also can access the WebUI http://localhost:8161/admin/

Now I want to start my service [TimeService](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/ni920/timeserviceplain) I have the following settings in the container:

```
docker service create --name timeservice -p 7000:7000  --replicas 1 --network mynet ni920/timeserviceplain:latest
```

```
java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616
java.naming.user=admin
java.naming.password=admin
io.jexxa.rest.host=0.0.0.0
io.jexxa.rest.port=7000
```

So it should connect via `tcp://localhost:61616` with the `ActiveMQ` but it doesn't.

Do you guys have any clue what I should try by the way the communication works perfectly in a none `Swarm` environment or in a `Kubernetes-Pod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your containers to communicate witch each other, you can use their names then let network driver resolves their ips.

Here is the [network driver summary](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-driver-summary) from docker docs:

> - **User-defined bridge networks** are best when you need multiple containers to communicate on the same Docker host.
> - **Host networks** are best when the network stack should not be isolated from the Docker host, but you want other aspects of the container to be isolated.
> - **Overlay networks** are best when you need containers running on different Docker hosts to communicate, or when multiple applications work together using swarm services.
> - **Macvlan networks** are best when you are migrating from a VM setup or need your containers to look like physical hosts on your network, each with a unique MAC address.
> - **Third-party network plugins** allow you to integrate Docker with specialized network stacks.

---

In your case, replace **localhost** with service name **activemq**.

```
java.naming.provider.url=tcp://activemq:61616
.
.
```